# apt-get update command results in 404 Not Found error

Tags: 13.10

Please help with this error.

```
sudo apt-get update

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages
 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `sudo nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
- Delete the `upubuntu-com-office-saucy.list` file
- Then run `sudo apt-get update`

The 404 Not Found will never comes for this PPA.

[How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Comment: I will do it in 2 mits. it says like that "You can accept an answer in 2 minute"